# Hide checkbox and label

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

THE SCENARIO:
I have an ul an li and a checkbox and label inside a repeater, these form all together a list of checkboxes. And i have an javascript file that controls the checkboxes behavior. 
I succeed to hide the checkboxes with javascript code, but when i tried to hide the label it didn't work.

I will post the code ASP.NET for a better understanding:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" DataSource="<%# GetSecondAreas(CurrentLocationName) %>">
<HeaderTemplate>
<ul>
</HeaderTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>
<li class="area">
<input type="checkbox" class="category" value="<%# string.Concat(CurrentLocation.Area1,"| ", CurrentLocation.Area2)%>" />
<label>
<%#CurrentLocation.Area2%>
</label>
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater2" runat="server" DataSource="<%# GetThirdAreas(CurrentLocation.Area2) %>">
<HeaderTemplate>
<ul>
</HeaderTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>
<li>
<input type="checkbox" class="category" value="<%#string.Concat(CurrentLocation.Area1,"| ", CurrentLocation.Area2,"| ", CurrentLocation.Area3)%>" />
<label id="last">
<%#CurrentLocation.Area3%>
</label>
</li>
</ItemTemplate>
<FooterTemplate>
</ul>
</FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
</li>
</ItemTemplate>
<FooterTemplate>
</ul>
</FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

And here is the javascript code:

```
function updateByArea(current) {
//If current is unchecked => uncheck all child checkboxes
if (current.attr("checked") == null || current.attr("checked") == "")
    $j(".area ul li input[value^='" + current.val() + "']:checked").removeAttr("checked").hide(); //checkbox
    $j('label[id="id_val"]').hide();
$j("#searchFilter .area>input:checkbox:checked").each(function (i, item) {
    $j(".area ul li input[value^='" + $j(item).val() + "']:not(:checked)").attr("checked", "checked").show(); //checkbox
    $j('label[id="id_val"]').show();
});
```

}

What i've posted here is what i tried just for the label with the id="last"

THE QUESTION:

Did i made correct the javascript code for the label, so when I tick the checkbox to hide and show the checkbox and the label together?

P.S: On the code that i have right now it hides just the checkbox.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

change

```
.hide();
```

to

```
.parent().hide();
```

This will select the parent [which should be the li] and hide it.